# Using a Module from Simple TypeScrypt File Causes Error "Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Tags: typescript, module, sweetalert2

In a Visual Studio 2019 web project, I am trying to use sweetalert2 in a simple TS file (no module). I have referenced the .js file of sweetalert2 from the CDN and I have added the file sweetalert2.d.ts inside my solution. Then I import the module in my test.ts file (see code), the TS compiler is happy and can find `Swal.fire()`. However, the generated test.js file has the import at the top and this causes an error in the browser saying imports cannot be used outside a module. If I manually remove the import from the generated test.js file, everything works fine.

How can I at the same time make the TS compiler find the module/namespace (Swal is a namespace inside the module) and still get the resulting test.js file to work in the browser?

test.ts

```
import Swal from "sweetalert2";

function test() {
    Swal.fire('Any fool can use a computer')
}
```

index.html (for test)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9.10.12/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>test();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Error in Chrome

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module